# Prevent negative values in NVD3 chart axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Hi I need to limit my line graphs with NVD3/D3 to having a Y axis with no negative numbers.  I'm trying to do that based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067595/nvd3-d3-change-y-axis-minimum-value) as such:

```
chart.y1Axis.scale().domain([0, maxValue])
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
```

But adding ".scale().domain([0, maxValue])" to the chain kills the entire chart.  I can't figure out how to do this basic thing and can't find an example that works.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`y1Axis.scale()` returns a scale object, which `.domain([0, maxValue])` modifies.

`.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'))` needs an axis object, not a scale object. To fix the problem, put `.scale()` after you're done modifying the axis:

```
chart.y1Axis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'))
    .tickValues([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21])
    .etc(...)
  .scale()
    .domain([0, maxValue])
```