# nvd3 lineChart forceY(0) still renders values below 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, nvd3.js

I have an issue with chart.forceY in the excellent nvd3. I have need to add a trend line to a line chart (with three datasets) which can occasionally render negative numbers, this causes the axes to render below 0 and draw the line below the zero line. This can be considered expected behaviour, but is unwanted in this instance.

I have played with [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/lBKFld?p=preview)

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'lineChart',
                height: 450,
                margin : {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 40,
                    left: 55
                },
                x: function(d){ return d.x; },
                y: function(d){ return d.y; },
                useInteractiveGuideline: true,
                forceY: 0,
...
```

to see whether I can get chart.forceY(0) to limit the y-axis minimum to zero, but it always insists of drawing everything with a negative value. Fidel90, [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067595/nvd3-d3-change-y-axis-minimum-value), suggested this method. Ranges [-10,0,10] work fine, but [0,10] still renders what is below the 0 line.

The context of the charts required dictates that negative numbers can never happen, but they can exist in a trend if the values allow steep enough changes over a short enough period of time. We used to use flot for these and forcing a minimum of 0 worked a treat, but due to needing more advanced charting with greater control, d3 (angular nvd3) was chosen. 

How can I force the chart to only render values with a positive value and ignore - not render anything below 0 on the y-axis?